# Create a page to experiment with SQL injection

Tags: web-application, attacks, penetration-test, sql-injection, asp.net

This semester, I have taken a course on Information Security and my project for this course is to implement an SQL injection to obtain admin privileges. For this I first download Havij software (Advanced SQL Injection Tool) to study how it works.

After some time and tests, I know how to hack some of the information of a website. Now, I want to create my own page of the same kind as I found in the example of Havij software at http://www.target.com/index.asp?id=123. How can I make my own page to study penetration testing and hacking of my own information so that I can learn more from it?

Comment: Downvoter: What's wrong with this question? Asking how to setup a testing environment for yourself to learn from seems like a totally legit question to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[From SQL injection to shell](https://pentesterlab.com/exercises/from_sqli_to_shell) - this will walk you through manual exploitation of sql injection, download the vm and follow the step by step pdf.

there is a difference in understanding and doing. this will help :)

Comment: Welcome to IT Security! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 3):

This website is really useful if you need information on SQL injections : http://www.websec.ca/kb/sql_injection

Comment: You can find lists of vulnerable applications [here](http://bailey.st/blog/2010/09/14/pentest-lab-vulnerable-servers-applications-list/) and [here](http://blog.taddong.com/2011/10/hacking-vulnerable-web-applications.html).

Answer (score 1):

Why make your own? Why not use [webgoat](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category%3aOWASP_WebGoat_Project) or [mutillidae](http://www.irongeek.com/i.php?page=mutillidae/mutillidae-deliberately-vulnerable-php-owasp-top-10)? There are many such pre-made targets for you to learn from.

Comment: Yes, that's also a good practice and it will save my time. I appreciate your links.