# are there any services to test nmap

Tags: legal, nmap

While playing with nmap, I have started to wonder: are there any ip addresses which were specifically made to learn how to use nmap.

(As far as I understood I can not just scan any ip address, because this is illegal)

On SE I have seen [posts](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/24133/15912) with the examples of sites for sql-injections, so I hope that there is something out there to learn how to use nmap. Currently I am scanning my own machine 127.0.0.1 and my own web server, which is not so much fun.

Comment: http://scanme.nmap.org/

Comment: @TerryChia Next step:  "So, what am I supposed to see when I run [given nmap command] against scanme.nmap.org?" - is there a site that hosts this information?  It doesn't seem readily apparent from the ScanMe homepage.

Comment: nmap should tell you what in the scan responds to connection attempts.  If you're new to nmap and aren't sure what to do, try zenmap http://nmap.org/zenmap/ , it's handy even for experts and shows you the command line options it used in the scan.

Answer (score 3):

As Terry said in the comments, you can test out nmap on [scanme.nmap.org](http://scanme.nmap.org/), which is designed for exactly this.

You could also set up a machine in a VM, or on [Amazon EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) for testing, with various services and firewall configurations, in order to see how nmap's results change depending on your OS and configuration.

Answer (score 0):

The many 'boot to root' VMs that are out there have very well-known nmap signatures that you can use to test, verify, and learn about nmap.